# VSCode: Webview extension: share data structure definition between js and ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension using a webview. For communication between vscode (typescript) and webview (javascript) I send data structures back and forth using `postMessage` and `receiveMessage`.

Is there any way to allow both sides (typescript and javascript) to access the same data structure definition?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What would JavaScript do with a TypeScript data structure definition? It doesn't have types.

Comment: I'd define it in Javascript, instead of Typescript - which is also practical, as Typescript will become compiled to JS later.